# Django: ModelForm doesn't call clean_xxxx when validated?

Tags: django, django-forms

**models.py**

```
class OrderImage(TimeStampedModel):
    img = models.ImageField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

**forms.py**

```
class OrderImageForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = OrderImage
    fields = ['img', 'name',]

def clean_name(self):
    print("name")

def clean_img(self):
    print("img")
```

I break `clean_img` with `from IPython import embed; embed();`

And I test it,

```
def test_a(self):
    form = OrderImageForm({
        'img':'b',
        'name':'a'
    })
    form.is_valid()
```

When I test, it only print `name`....

Why does it happen?

Comment: Hmm, that should work. Are you sure your indentation is correct?

Comment: yeah, I successfully pass all test without any errors. When I changed `clean_image` with `clean`, `embed()` breaks the code.

Comment: Try removing *args and kwargs ( clean_image(self))

Comment: @Sayse It doens't stop the code, either...

Comment: Do you have more than one orderimage class or orderimageform? As stated already,  it should work

Comment: It only prints name because your model has no img field...

Comment: @Sayse it was my mistake. Same thing happen even I correct field name.